# Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0,

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have installed vs2013 but not getting correct run time setup. anyone plz provide me correct setup of crystal report for vs2013 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Use [this link](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_1.zip) to download the CR for X64 machines.